# How to use a proxy with NodeJS Selenium Driver?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-automation

I'm trying to mask my identity for my automation program although I am having trouble with setting a proxy for my driver.

```
var ChromeDriver = require('chromedriver');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    proxy = require('selenium-webdriver/proxy');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setProxy(proxy.manual({http: '47.88.53.111:3128'}))
    .build();
```

When I run the driver, the IP does not change to the proxy address like I would like it to.

I'm new to javascript so please let me know if you can spot anything I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 3):

```
const { Builder } =  require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

let addr = '47.88.53.111:3128'
let opt = new chrome.Options().addArguments(`--proxy-server=http://${addr}`)

const driver = new Builder()
 .forBrowser('chrome')
 .setChromeOptions(opt)
 .build()

driver.get('http://whatismyip.host/')
 .then(() => console.log('DONE'))
```